# My gulp task to "concat" and "dest" my .css file, is only running if I run 2 times

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

The concatenation and destination to my public/assets/css is only working if i run 2 times the task. Even if I run just the app.css (npm run dev app.css), only work if I run twice.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
const uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss')
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const babel = require('gulp-babel')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('app', ['app.html', 'app.sass', 'app.js', 'app.assets', 'app.css'])

gulp.task('app.html', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true, removeComments: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
})

gulp.task('app.sass', function () {
    gulp.src(['sass/main.scss'])
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

gulp.task('app.css', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.css'])
        .pipe(uglifycss({ "uglyComments": true}))
        .pipe(concat('app.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'))
})

gulp.task('app.js', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'))
})

gulp.task('app.assets', function(){
    gulp.src(['assets/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets'))

})
```

Comment: Your SASS and CSS should probably be in one task. Is that the problem?

Comment: I tried, but also need to run twice to work: gulp.task('app.sass', function () {
    gulp.src(['sass/main.scss'])
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.css'])
        .pipe(uglifycss({ "uglyComments": true}))
        .pipe(concat('app.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'))
})

Comment: @christo8989 the problem is that the task is working when I run twice. I would like to run on the first time, for future updates on the code or to someone that will maintenance the code.

Comment: You're writing the task incorrectly if you want it in one task. The sequence plugin is a good option. I'll also post my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gulp to respect the order of the task dependencies you defined, you need to tell it when the task is done.

To do so, you need to return a [stream](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options), a promise, or call the [task function `callback` parameter](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#accept-a-callback).

Since your tasks are pretty basic, just returning the stream should be enough.

```
gulp.task('app.sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(['sass/main.scss']) // notice the return here
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

// make the sass task a dependency of the CSS task
gulp.task('app.css', ['app.sass'], function(){
    return gulp.src(['app/**/*.css']) // notice the return here
        .pipe(uglifycss({ "uglyComments": true}))
        .pipe(concat('app.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});
```

Now you don't need the `app.sass` since it will run before `app.css`.

```
gulp.task('app', ['app.html', 'app.js', 'app.assets', 'app.css'])
```

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow, and let you know about the results.

Comment: @LucasTelesx I've put 2 tasks as an example, but you should apply the `return` to all your tasks.

Comment: Good Morning, the console give me this error: `gulp.task('app.css', ['app.sass'] function(){
                                ^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @LucasTelesx there was a missing comma between `['app.sass']` and `function`

Comment: Thank you so much, you did it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your tasks should be waiting for a result from the previous task. You can't just run several tasks in one time.

Try with gulp-sequence plugin. Install gulp-sequence and add the following line on the top of your gulpfile.js:

```
const gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence')
```

Replace your current 'app' task by:

```
gulp.task('app', gulpSequence('app.html', 'app.sass', 'app.js', 'app.assets', 'app.css'))
```

Comment: Sorry but not worked. I also tried to put on my main 'gulpfile,js';       const gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence')
const gulp = require('gulp')

require('./gulpTasks/app')
require('./gulpTasks/server')


gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.start('app', 'server')
})